# Python scipy function does not take global variables

Tags: python, scipy, global-variables

I am trying to solve a system of linear equations. Because there are a lot of them I am using `Newton-Krylov` method, from `scipy.minimize`. For those unfamiliar, it takes a set of equations, and an initial guess. However, the definition of the set of equations, is dependent on its own parameters, but there is no way of inputting those into the `Newton-Krylov` solver.

Below is the code that I have written

```
import networkx as nx
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np
import math
from scipy.optimize import newton_krylov

def gen_r_scores_anderson():
    datasets = [
        'WTW_decades/1960wtw.txt'
            ]
    z_scores = []
    for i in range(1):
        data = np.genfromtxt(datasets[i], dtype=[('a','|S5'),('b','|S5'),('amount','f8')], usemask=True) #import data
        binary_edgelist = create_edgelist_binary(data) #create edgelist
        H = nx.DiGraph() #create graph
        H.add_edges_from(binary_edgelist) #insert edgelist in graph
        B = nx.adjacency_matrix(H) #make H into an adjacency matrix
        n = len(H.nodes()) #define number of nodes n
        H_nodes = np.asarray(H.nodes()) #define the name of the nodes in an array

        rec = recip(B.todense(),n) #counts the amount of reciprocating links between i and j
        onrec = out_non_recip(B.todense(),n) #links going from i to j
        inrec = in_non_recip(B.todense(),n) #amount of links going from j to i

        #now we calculate the x and y values using Newtons method

        u = [0.5]*3*n # initial guess
        s = newton_krylov(f, u) # << this is where the problem lies
    return(t)

t_score = gen_r_scores_anderson()
print(t_score)
```

where the function `f`, the input for the newton_krylov method, is defined as follows

```
def f(w, n, onrec, inrec, rec):
    F = [0]*3*n
    for i in range(n): 
        F[i] = -onrec[i]
        F[n+i] = -inrec[i]
        F[(2*n)+i] = -rec[i]
        for j in range(n):
            if i == j:
                None
            else:
                F[i] += (w[i]*w[n+j])/(1+w[i]*w[n+j]+w[j]*w[n+i]+w[2*n+i]*w[2*n+j])
                F[n+i] += (w[j]*w[n+i])/(1+w[i]*w[n+j]+w[j]*w[n+i]+w[2*n+i]*w[2*n+j])
                F[2*n+i] += (w[(2*n)+i]*w[(2*n)+j])/(1+w[i]*w[n+j]+w[j]*w[n+i]+w[2*n+i]*w[2*n+j])
    return(F)
```

I have read about globals, but with some messing around, have not figured how to use them in this scenario. Thanks for the help in advance, hopefully you can help me hand my thesis in on time!

Comment: maybe this question is a little bit too difficult, or maybe I am being a little bit unclear. Please tell me how I can improve the question!

Comment: Which variables are the problem?  `onrec` etc?  I'd  just omit them from the function definition.  Then they'll their values from the calling environment.  And since you aren't changing them you don't need to define them as `global`.  (Some `optimize` code lets you specify a extra `args` tuple, but this apparently does not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use globals, you need to declare them within the function.

For example:

```
variable = 0
def function():
     global variable
     variable += 1
function()
```

This code increments the global variable. However, this function does not:

```
variable = 0
def function(input):
    global variable
    input += 1
function(variable)
```

The local variable is a copy of the global

Comment: But do I define these inside the `f` function, or inside the `inrec`, `onrec` and `rec` functions?

Comment: I'm going to look deeper at your code and get back to you

Comment: I have figured it out, you gave me the push in the right direction! I will post the answer!

Comment: Just to clarify, inrec, onrec, and rec are lists?

Comment: I was going to say that you can make those global variables and call them when you want to use the solver

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly different, as I now use the anderson method, but is basically the same.

```
start1 = time.time()

def gen_r_scores_anderson():
    datasets = [
        'WTW_decades/1960wtw.txt'
            ]
    z_scores = []
    for i in range(1):
        data = np.genfromtxt(datasets[i], dtype=[('a','|S5'),('b','|S5'),('amount','f8')], usemask=True) #import data
        binary_edgelist = create_edgelist_binary(data) #create edgelist
        H = nx.DiGraph() #create graph
        H.add_edges_from(binary_edgelist) #insert edgelist in graph
        B = nx.adjacency_matrix(H) #make H into an adjacency matrix
        global n
        n = len(H.nodes()) #define number of nodes n
        H_nodes = np.asarray(H.nodes()) #define the name of the nodes in an array

        global rec
        rec = recip(B.todense(),n) #counts the amount of reciprocating links between i and j

        global onrec
        onrec = out_non_recip(B.todense(),n) #links going from i to j

        global inrec
        inrec = in_non_recip(B.todense(),n) #amount of links going from j to i

        #now we calculate the x and y values using Newtons method

        u = [0.5]*3*n
        s = anderson(f, u)
        t = makematrixpos(s)
    return(t)

t_score = gen_r_scores_anderson()
print(t_score)

end1 = time.time()
print(end1 - start1)
```

So what I have done is put the `global` in the `gen_all_data` function instead of putting the `global` in `f`, `inrec`, `rec` or `onrec` functions